# Django Mysql: MigrationSchemaMissing Error Windows

Tags: python, mysql, django

SO has a lot of questions on this error, but I am unabble to get rid of it. I am trying to connect my Django app to a MySQL database, but keep getting this error:

```
 raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table ((1064, "pa
rse sql 'CREATE TABLE `django_migrations` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `app` varchar(255)
NOT NULL, `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `applied` datetime(6) NOT NULL)' error: syntax error at position 8 near
create"))
```

I have initialised a new project and just changed settings.py to this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'some name',
        'HOST': 'some ip',
        'PORT': '3306',
        # 'USER': '',
        # 'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            # 'sql_mode': 'traditional',
             'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
    }
}
```

I have removed Options, but it does not work.
I have used different Django versions and mySqlClient versions, but still can't get it to work.

My current Django and mysqlclient are the latest versions, i.e. mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1 and django-2.2.3.

Comment: Did you give your user proper rights to create/alter/remove/... tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL user might not have permissions to create the database.

You can use fix this by running these commands on the MySQL console :

```
grant usage on schema public to username;
grant create on schema public to username;
```

Comment: I only need to query the database. Will rights be needed in that scenario too?

Comment: @Nisha: no, since you migrate the database (create tables, etc.), you should grant permission to the user to do that.

Comment: Also, When I do python manage. py inspectdb I do get the models.

Comment: Okay I will try to do that.

Comment: @Nisha: that is not strange. But Django maintains an extra table `django_migrations` (together with other tables) to keep track of what migrations it has done, and still should do.